# Unable to login to Github or Facebook or any such site using Python requests?

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, github, python-requests

I am using the following code:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()

login_data = dict(login='username', password='my_password')
s.post('https://github.com/login/', data=login_data)

r = s.get('https://github.com/')
print(r.text)
```

The content printed is from the login page and not the page after that. I have also tried:

```
import requests

url = 'http://facebook.com'
values = {'email': 'username', 'pass': 'my_password'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.text)
```

Both times, the data printed is from the login page and not the p[age after that what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably can't post to those forms directly. What are you trying to accomplish? Using a Git / GitHub or Facebook library is likely a better approach. If you would prefer not to use a library, consider using these sites' APIs.

Comment: i guess they are trying to prevent people from botting logins, as account could get hacked easily that way

Comment: Actually, I am just learning about this module and it would have felt nice to see it working and encourage me to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requests` module isn't a web browser. Although you *can* do some pretty cool stuff with it there are situations where it isn't an appropriate tool.

Many websites use security on their forms to reduce abuse. A popular strategy is to use a [cross-site request forgery token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). This is a hidden field whose value is generated server-side and then included in the form. When the form gets submitted the server can make sure that the hidden input is present and valid.

This is one strategy for preventing submission of the form from somewhere else. If you look at the source for GitHub's login page you'll see a hidden input inside the form named `authenticity_token` which is probably used for exactly that.

If you want to play with `requests`' POST feature you can use something like https://httpbin.org/. Here, you should be able to POST a message and get an appropriate response.

For interacting with GitHub or Facebook you should use a [library](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) or a [published API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Comment: Is there any other website, where I can use requests to login? I have used it on httpbin, it would have been much more exciting to use to in practical life to login somewhere. :)

Comment: @SanJeetSingh, I'm not sure that "logging into a website" is the best use for `requests`. But you should be able to test out its POST functionality using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) that I mentioned in my answer. There are lots of options here; something like [creating an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) or [adding a comment to an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment) might be a good place to start. The API does [require authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) for many endpoints.

Comment: Did you mean that I could use requests to create an issue or add a comment?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh, yes, as outlined in the links in my comment.